# How to check for space in backend on parallel upload (thread safety)

Tags: php, multithreading, file-upload, parallel-processing, thread-safety

I'm using dropzone.js to build an image uploading system, where users can upload up to 8 images each. Because of that parameter, I have to make a check in the backend and only persist the image on success, but... Using dropzone.js I can make the single request into parallel uploads and then get the response much faster on each one of the images (UX). Before dropzone.js even makes the request, I have some frontend validation to check if the limit is reached.

Example: Let's say the user has already uploaded 6 images. Then they try to upload 6 more using the parallel uploading system. If I make each of the requests return the number of current images, they will all return 6 and therefore they are all uploaded and persisted.

My question is, how can I count if the limit is reached in the backend? If I just make a current image count, all the parallel requests, will return the same result, because they all hit the backend at the same time, I guess. Because of that they are all persisted.

I look forward to hear from you!
Thanks.

Comment: Well, add the number of pics selected on the client side to the number you receive back from the server side, I'd say.

Comment: Sure, that's one option, but it's not optional... I need the backend to be able to handle the validation on it's own, without client helpers...

Comment: No real solution is possible for a server side only validation upfront, since not all information is present there. So all you can do is react later, when the limit is broken. Which actually is fine and a wide spread strategy: you combine client side and server side validation. Client side validation is important for UX, server side validation is important for security. So you combine the best of both worlds. Sure, one could manipulate the client side validation, but that would not really lead anywhere, since the server side validation would still prevent miss usage, so things are safe.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you, @arkascha